# Can I use a field from a static block and assign it to the class field?

Tags: java, static-block

I want to number the races depending on their location and it should be done when creating the car in the constructor. The question is can I get a field from a static block and assign its value to the vehicle class field?

```
public class Vehicle {

    static {
        Locale[] loc = {Locale.US, Locale.JAPAN, Locale.ITALIAN,};
        int[] beginNr = {100, 1000, 10000};
        int initNr = 200;
        Locale defLoc = Locale.getDefault();

        for (int i=0; i<loc.length; i++)
            if (defLoc.equals(loc[i])){
                initNr  = beginNr[i];
                break;
            }
    }

    private int width, height, lenght, weight;
    private Person owner;
    private VehicleStatus status;
    private static int count;
    private int currentNumber;


    public Vehicle(Person owner, int width, int height, int lenght, int weight) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.lenght = lenght;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.owner = owner;
        status = STOPPED;
        currentNumber = ++count;
    }
```

I want the value of the `initNr` field to be assigned to the `currentNumber` field.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to create an automatic numbering of a car based on location?

Comment: You can simply refer to the field `currentNumber` in your static block, instead of `initNr`.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is can I get a field from a static block and assign its value to the vehicle class field?

No, because you don't declare fields in a static initializer: those are *local variables*. They can only be accessed within that block.

If you want a field, declare it so:

```
static int initNr = 200;

static {
  // Stuff where you change the value of initNr.
}
```

Now you can refer to `initNr` in the rest of the class.